# access file on linux server through php

Tags: php, linux

My php is installed on localhost. I am trying to access a file which is on linux server through PHP. Now I use Putty to access this file. I am logging in with host name 10.8.0.7, I am using `more /dba/.passwords_admin` command to access this file. It works fine with Putty. But, I am confused how do I access this file from PHP. I tried fopen, file_get_contents; but it is not working. Any suggestions on how to access this file???

Thank You

Comment: does the web server user have read access for that file?

Comment: yes. the thing is when i asked my supervisor about this, he said you can't use fopen to read this file cause it is in linux. and he wants me to figure out by myself.

Comment: `You're loggin in`, I think that's your main issue: are you logging in when accessing the file via php, too? if so: which user? same as putty? same protocol (SSH,telnet,RAW,...)?

Comment: you putty in as root or another user? web services running as www-data? so you can either chmod the file to allow everyone to read it or add www-root to a group that can read it.  exec('more /dba/.passwords_admin'); is another way but you still need to sort out permissions

Comment: `$file = fopen ("http://www.milinddoshi.info/temp/1.cfg", "r");
if (!$file) {
echo "<p>Unable to open remote file.\n";
exit;
}
while (!feof ($file)) {
$line = fgets ($file, 1024);
echo $line;
}
fclose($file);` This works fine on my friend's website and on localhost. But same thing with `$file = fopen ("10.8.0.7/dba/.passwords_admin", "r") doesn't work

Comment: `-rw-rw-r--  1 mysql dba 107506 Aug 13 05:01 /dba/.passwords_admin` These are the permissions of a file